# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value.This is not permitted

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT 
   concat(section.SectionType,Item.Size,'-',Grade.Grade)as 'item'
  ,sum([RemainingQuantity]) as 'Quantity'
  ,[Length]
  ,[Width]
  ,loc.Location
 ,(Select sum(ODRM.[QuantityBooking]-ODRM.ChangeLocationQty) 
    FROM [dbo].[OrderDetailsRawMaterial] ODRM
    inner join RawMaterial rawmat on rawmat.id=[FK_RawMaterial]
    Where  ODRM.[QuantityBooking] >ODRM.ChangeLocationQty
    Group By rawmat.FK_Item
    )as'QuantityBooking' 
FROM [dbo].[RawMaterial]
inner join item on Item.id=FK_Item
inner join SectionType section on section.id=Item.FK_SectionType
inner join Grade on Grade.id=Item.FK_Grade
inner join Location loc on loc.id=FK_Location
Where show=1 and ShowQuality=1 and [RemainingQuantity]>0
Group By
 concat(section.SectionType,Item.Size,'-',Grade.Grade)
 , [Length]
  ,[Width]
  ,loc.Location
Order By concat(section.SectionType,Item.Size,'-',Grade.Grade)
```

but when i run the query i get this error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message explains what's wrong. You tried to use a query in the SELECT clause. That's a bad idea to begin with and can only work if that query returns a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group by naturally produces more than one rows whereas subquery in select statement needs only one.

You need to change group by in the way that outer query will be related with inner query.

the trick is to add `awmat.FK_Item = item.Id`

Change the inner query like below

```
select sum(ODRM.[QuantityBooking]-ODRM.ChangeLocationQty) 
FROM [dbo].[OrderDetailsRawMaterial] ODRM
inner join RawMaterial rawmat on rawmat.id=[FK_RawMaterial]
Where  ODRM.[QuantityBooking] >ODRM.ChangeLocationQty
  and awmat.FK_Item = item.Id
```

Comment: It would be even better if that was moved from the SELECT clause to a `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu Thank you very much for your help ,I Have another problem when i add more group by to the sub query(Group By rawmat.FK_Item,rawmat.[Length] ,rawmat.[Width]) I get the same error but this time I get results with Query completed with errors